# Numerical approximation of a dx/dy derivative

Tags: derivatives, estimation

I have to find numerical approximation of the derivative of **dx/dy** where **y(x)=exp(sin^2(x)+cos(x)exp(x^2))** at the point **Xo=0.5**. As far as I understand, I have to pick a close point to X0 for example 0.501 and calculate the function f'(0.5)=(f(0.501)-f(0.5))/(0.501-0.5) but it is very complicated. Any help?

Comment: use the formula $$\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$ with a small $h$

Comment: Also, why do you need to calculate it numerically when you can calculate it precisely?

Comment: This is the exersice to find and estimation and compare it to the solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate
an approximate derivative,
it is better to use
$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}
$
rather than
$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$,
because its error
is 
$O(h^2)$
compared with the
$O(h)$
of the standard form.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the derivative, then you can calculate it using the chain rule. In that case, if you are unable to find the derivative, you should say so in the question.

If your task is to specifically calculate a numerical approximation, then simply take your favorite programming language or tool and write a function that calculates $f(x)$. In Python, the function can be written in one line, and it looks something like

```
import math

def f(x):
    return math.exp(math.sin(x)**2.....)
```

then take some small value of $h$ and calculate the approximation of the derivative:

```
h=0.001
x=0.5
print (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h
```